# Cambiar Imagen de FAB según Fragment no funciona

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy intentando cambiar la imagen de mi `FAB (FloatingActionButton)` según el `Fragment` en el que se encuentre, pero no me está funcionando ya que al cambiar de `Fragment`, la imagen sigue siendo la misma. Para aplicar el cambio lo que hago es lo siguiente, tengo este método:

```
private void CambiarImagenFab(){
  final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); // cambiar `nav_host_fragment` según el que uses

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

            if (currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add);

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof SlideshowFragment) {
                binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof GalleryFragment) {
                binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
            }
        }
}
```

A este método lo ejecuto tanto en el `onCreate` como en el `onResume` de mi `MainActivity` pero no cambia la imagen cada vez que cambio el `Fragment`.

Comment: Intentaste con setImageDrawable() ? Depende si estás usando Support Library o no

Comment: No, de hecho la solución fue usar el `NavControler.OnDestinationChangedListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjunto la solución que hallé, esto debe realizarse en el onCreateView:

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener destinationChangedListener = new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
            binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_auto_blanco);

        } else if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
        }
    }
};
```